# Can any one give me some advice to make my for loop more efficient?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, performance, for-loop

So I have this for loop with 36 if-queries inside. Any advice on making it more efficient?
You can view the complete code  [here](http://pastie.org/private/e7xjivdnj6xdbxtjtutrpw)

Here's a sample of what it looks like:

```
$numbers = range(1, 36);
shuffle($numbers);  
for ($m =0; $m<37; $m++){
    if ($numbers[$m] == "1"){
        $mirza[$m] = "RUTHIE";
        $mage[$m] = "3";
        $mquote[$m] = "I get to learn a lot of new things here, like sign language!";
        $link[$m] = "http://www.google.com";
    }

    if ($numbers[$m] == "2"){
        $mirza[$m] = "AIDA";
        $mage[$m] = "82";
        $mquote[$m] = "This is like a club and I know and like all the members. It's good therapy.";
        $link[$m] = "/about/";
    }

    if ($numbers[$m] == "3"){
        $mirza[$m] = "AMIRE";
        $mage[$m] = "4";
        $mquote[$m] = "I am learning how to share and make friends.";
        $link[$m] = "/about/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to make this "more efficient".  Is it running slow?  It looks just about as efficient as you can get without really obscuring what's going on...

Comment: mizra - you seem to be happy with a solution you've found but i really suggest you keep you looking. ive posted something slightly better but you really ought to look into a database with fields for `mirza, mage, mquote,` and `link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have this much data it really should be in a database (maybe XML or document style) or a text file.

Still, I'll show you a way to improve this by hard-coding all the data in one place and eliminating the need for any if or switch statements.  You should AT VERY LEAST change to switch statements, better still hard-code all the data in one place (below), better still get a database or CSV text file storing these values.

```
$data = array( 
         array('mirza' => 'RUTHIE', 'mage' => '3', 'mquote' => 'I get to learn a lot of new things here, like sign language!', 'link' => 'http://www.google.com'),
         array(......
             );

$numbers = range(1, 36);
shuffle($numbers);  
for ($m =0; $m<37; $m++){
     $index = $numbers[$m];
     $mirza[$m] = $data[$index]['mirza'];
     $mage[$m] = $data[$index]['mage'];
     $mquote[$m] = $data[$index]['mage'];
     $link[$m] = $data[$index]['link'];
 }
```

Just to be clear, the 'efficiency' issue here isn't so much speed (though this way is faster).  Its that what you have is a nightmare to maintain and change.

You might do better to seriously reconsider the design of your app, specifically making an object with `mirza, mage, mquote, link` as fields.

Comment: There might be an off-by-one issue here, but that can be remedied either by changhing `$numbers` to begin at 0 our changing `$data` to begin at 1

Answer (score 3):

Changing your if-s to a switch with appropriate breaks or even at worse if..elseif..etc would mean that not all ifs have to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that you feel you simply have too many "if" statements? Try a switch statement. Technically speaking, your loop is about as efficient as possible (using big-O method of evaluating efficiency).

```
for ($m =0; $m<37; $m++){
    switch($numbers[$m])
    {
        case 1:
            $mirza[$m] = "RUTHIE";
            $mage[$m] = "3";
            $mquote[$m] = "I get to learn a lot of new things here, like sign language!";
            $link[$m] = "http://www.google.com";
        break;
        case 2:
            $mirza[$m] = "AIDA";
            $mage[$m] = "82";
            $mquote[$m] = "This is like a club and I know and like all the members. It's good therapy.";
            $link[$m] = "/about/";
        break;
        case 3:
            $mirza[$m] = "AMIRE";
            $mage[$m] = "4";
            $mquote[$m] = "I am learning how to share and make friends.";
            $link[$m] = "/about/";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A switch statement is not equivalent to his separate if statements.

Comment: No it isn't. But I think that was the point, since the question was how the original poster could make his code more efficient. The output should be equivalent, however.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it's already as fast as you may ever need.

The only way to make it faster is to look at sites benchmarking PHP and to adjust this or that to easy the most efficent PHP internals.

Since PHP internals may change over time (with PHP updates), unless you regulary benchmark your code I'd say you have not that much to gain, especially with code that simple.

For example you may try to change

```
$numbers[$m] == "2"
```

with

```
$numbers[$m] === 2
```

or

```
$numbers[$m] === "2"
```

But if you don't benchmark your code (ex. putting it in a function and measure the execution time over 10.000 iterations) you're gonna be blind about improvements. PHP internals speed don't always behave as you expect it.

(the same goes with the answer you got about the switch statement. Try it, but benchmark !)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try to work with data structures, and put all these values in an array of the same type as the data structure. That way, if you later need to access the values again with the same number-to-value relationship, you won't have to redefine everything like you have done here. All you would have to do then is to use array indices to access the values.

Comment: PHP has no strict "type" system (similar to python in that regard). Since the data seems to be unique anyway, he is doing this now. Rather than matching arrayA[0] to arrayB[0] he simply sets arrayA[0] = "His string"

Comment: @RageD he is definitely on to something.  no offense to your answer, but the use of if statements in this case is ridiculous, and switches are only marginally better.  the real issue is that there is no need for conditionals of any kind.